# Can't create multiple labels with same key in Kubernetes 1.19

Tags: kubernetes

Is there a way to have the same label key but different values for a pod. For example, can a pod have labels as "app=db" and "app=web". I tried to use kubectl label command but it picks only one label.

Comment: Does not sound correct. Think about why would you do this.

Comment: This was one of the questions I encountered in CKAD exam: ""You have rolled out a new pod to your infrastructure and now you need to allow it to communicate
with the web and storage pods but nothing else. Given the running pod - newpod edit it to use a network policy that will allow it to send and receive traffic only to and from the web and storage pods."". Please note modification of network policy was not allowed

Comment: Question does not talk about assigning different values to to same label. If you think labels assigning labels will solve your problem, then IMHO, you should think about using multiple labels. "front-end=web", "back-end=db"

Comment: did you figure out the answer to this?

Comment: I'm also stumped on this too. For me, one network policy has a selector that matches labels "app=key1", and the other network policy has a selector that matches "app=key2" I need to apply both policies to a pod, and I don't have access to modify the network policies, or create a new one.

Answer (score 5):

Labels are a `map[string]string` so you are correct, this is not possible.